# Do we need to make all methods async

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I implemented an Api which has a controller which has a call tree like below.

```
public async Task<Collection<United.Service.Presentation.LoyaltyModel.Program>> GetRewardPrograms(string languageCode)
{
           
                return await _referenceDataDomain.GetRewardPrograms(languageCode).ConfigureAwait(false);
            
          
}
```

```
    public async Task<Collection<Program>> GetRewardPrograms(string languageCode)
        {
            return  await _referenceDataProvider.GetRewardPrograms(languageCode).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

```
 public async Task<Collection<Program>> GetRewardPrograms(string languageCode)
        {
           
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(languageCode))
            {
                languageCode = _constants.LANGUAGE_CODE_EN_US;
            }
            var rewardProgramsSet = new Collection<Program>();
            var format = CacheKeysDictionary.CacheKeyFormat(CacheKeysDictionary.RewardPrograms);
            var cacheKey = string.Format(format, languageCode);

            var cacheValue = await _cacheUtility.GetCacheItemAsync<Collection<Program>>(cacheKey).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (cacheValue != null && cacheValue.Any())
                return cacheValue;

            if (_commonConfig.UseLoyaltyService())
            {
                try
                {
                    var cslHttpClient = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICSLServiceProxy>();
                    var queryStringParams = new NameValueCollection() { { "languageCode", languageCode } };

                    var result = await cslHttpClient.GetAsync<NameValueCollection, RewardProgramsReferenceData>(_commonConfig.LoyaltyServiceUrl(),
                                                "ReferenceDataRewardProgram/idType/a", queryStringParams, _commonConfig.TimeOutDefault());

                    if (result != null && result.ResponseData != null && result.ResponseData.referenceDataRewardProgramList.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in result.ResponseData.referenceDataRewardProgramList)
                        {
                            var program = new Program
                            {
                                ProgramID = item.ProgramID.ToInt32(),
                                Code = item.ProgramCode,
                                Description = item.Description,
                                Language = new Language { LanguageCode = languageCode }
                            };

                            rewardProgramsSet.Add(program);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }

            if (rewardProgramsSet != null && rewardProgramsSet.Any())
            {
                await _cacheUtility.SetCacheItemAsync(cacheKey, rewardProgramsSet).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            return rewardProgramsSet;
        }
```

I got a code review feedback that since am making all method async and second block of code is not doing any async operation I should return task instead of using async method since adding async would internally make my method into state machine and that would create some performance issues, reviewer referred me this article
https://medium.com/@deep_blue_day/long-story-short-async-await-best-practices-in-net-1f39d7d84050 , please can somebody guide me if there is a flaw in above approach.

Comment: your first two code sections look very similar, apart from the second one doesn't have the async keyword and so won't compile...are they both meant to be there?

Comment: @Dave thanks for your reply, updated second block it does have async qualifier, in this particular case its not doing anything but just returning the result but in other cases we do have business logic implemented and all our methods are using refdataprovider through domain object so for consistency we are making this call

Comment: This is called *task forwarding*, it saves a `IAsyncStateMachine` implementation and affords you a small efficiency, but care needs to be taken that the method cannot throw itself, otherwise you would need to *catch* the *exception* and place it on the task to adhere to the semantics of the *async and await pattern*. I believe there is a Stephen Cleary blog somewhere that touches on this topic. The review was just saying you can safely remove the `async` and `await` keywords in your second example to forward the task

Comment: This would be good enough as an answer, however this is surely a duplicate

Comment: Like Michael said, removing async in these scenarios can have a small performance implication (but it is small, so you need to be calling it a lot or in a performance sensitive context to notice) - I did read once that unwrapping at each level like this can have some effect on exceptions handling and stack traces, but I can't remember and it may well be the same thing Michael said.

Comment: This is a very good article to read: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, please could you post this as an answer, I will accept this as an answer

Comment: @saurabhvats A link to an article isn't really an answer. Feel free to add your own :)

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer through this article posted by Stephan https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html, Thanks Jonathan for providing the link

following paragraph from the above link is the answer to my question:

Recommended Guidelines
I suggest following these guidelines:

Do not elide by default. Use the async and await for natural, easy-to-read code.
Do consider eliding when the method is just a passthrough or overload.

```
// Simple passthrough to next layer: elide.
Task<string> PassthroughAsync(int x) => _service.PassthroughAsync(x);

// Simple overloads for a method: elide.
async Task<string> OverloadsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    ... // Core implementation, using await.
}
Task<string> OverloadsAsync() => OverloadsAsync(CancellationToken.None);

// Non-trivial passthrough: use keywords.
async Task<string> PassthroughAsync(int x)
{
    // Reasoning: GetFirstArgument can throw.
    //  Even if it doesn't throw today, some yahoo can change it tomorrow, and it's not possible for them to know to change *this* method, too.
    return await _service.PassthroughAsync(GetFirstArgument(), x);
}

// Non-trivial overloads for a method: use keywords.
async Task<string> OverloadsAsync()
{
    // Same reasoning as above; GetDefaultCancellationTokenForThisScope can throw.
    return await OverloadsAsync(GetDefaultCancellationTokenForThisScope());
}
```

Comment: its usually best practice to summarize what content in the article that actually solved your problem/answered your question rather than just linking to it. Otherwise if that link dies in the future and some poor dev with the same question as your comes across this, they will be really gutted to see the answer has been lost.